# android imageview onclick listener

Tags: android

I have a image gallery and each image is a news. so i want to click a image and open a class for that image to show the news about it. My code is:

```
 gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

             public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                  Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ResimHaberGoster.class);
                intent1.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivityForResult(intent1, position);

             }

         });
```

at the  Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ResimHaberGoster.class); it gives me error and it changes this part to   Intent intent1 = new Intent();

So how should i go to a new class by clicking on the gallery

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code, try to change this :

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ResimHaberGoster.class);
```

with this :

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, ResimHaberGoster.class);
```

**explanation :**

when you pass `this` to your intent, the `this` is a reference of the actual onItemClickListener instance and not of your activity . so, to tell the programm that the context that you want to pass to your intent is the actual instance of your activity , you should use `YourActivity.this`

and sorry for my english ;

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

at `Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ResimHaberGoster.class);` `this` indicates the `OnItemClickListener` object. Instead you need the activity context. say your current activity is `MyActivity`, then instead of `this` use `MyActivity.this`in your intent constructor

Comment: as addition you can provide the application context by calling getApplicationContext() instead of this (this is a method inside the activity class). for views and adapter you need to pass the Context.

Comment: i think its better not to use app context for onClickListener, the reason being same as not using it in any View's constructor

Answer (score 1):

**frieza** is absolutely right. You can also use `getApplicationContext()`